# Magento accessories

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

If I have a store selling "iPhone 6" and "iPhone 6 yellow cover".
I assign "iPhone 6 yellow cover" as an accessory for "iPhone 6", and on "iPhone 6" product page everything looks good.

But I want to display on the product page for "iPhone 6 yellow cover" a similar block with "This product is compatible with" and to show "iPhone 6" there.

I spent 4 hours researching this on the internet without finding a solution, please point me into the right direction.
Thank you!

PS: assigning accessories is done automatically via a custom script, if that matters.

Comment: use `Related Products` tab in Products management and set in `iPhone` related `Yellow Cover` and in `Yellow Cover` related `iPhone`.

Comment: thanks, but that's not a solution, because "iPhone 6 yellow cover" can have it's own _related products_ .

Comment: OK. Next try - you can make attribute named as `Is accessory for product with SKU` or `with ID` and next check: if isset attribute - load block `This product is compatible with` based on id: `$accessoryforproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($isaccessoryvalue)->getData();`